# Create a variable in an IF statement

Tags: javascript

The code is supposed to take the user to a website, but I don't know how to put variables in an if statement. For example after they type in "Can you go to http://www.google.com", it would go to Google, and if they typed in "Can you go to http://www.yahoo.com" it would go to Yahoo

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var question=prompt ("Type in a question");
        if (question==("Can you go to " /*a website*/ )){
            window.location.href = /*the website that the person typed in after to*/;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't understand, do you want to test if what was typed is a valid url?

Comment: either a)the `if` is unnecessary or b)the `if` is validating the redirection and will only be redirected if it matches with the if... In case of 'b', just use `if (question==("Can you go to http://www.urlYouWantToAllowToBeRedirected.com"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Oleg said, use JavaScript's "Regular" Expressions.  To illustrate, this is your example made working with a regex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var question=prompt ("Type in a question");
    var match = /^Can you go to (.*)/.exec(question);
    if (match) {
        window.location.href = match[1];
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to match string against a pattern or extract data from it, your best bet in JavaScript is [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Use [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to both test if your string fits required pattern and extract the data you need in same check and then use extracted URL in your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the best approach, since the user could write something else at the prompt, not starting with "Can you go to".

But you can pick the answer of the prompt of which website to go to:

```
var question = prompt("Which website to go to", "");
//first test if not empty:
if (question != null && question != "") {
    window.location.href = question;
}
```

Obviously you should test if it is a valid website, etc.

Comment: I was trying to create an AI which can answer any thing you ask it, such as what is 3+3, it would answer, and if you told it to go to a website, it would. So your solution will not work.

Answer (score 0):

you want to parse the string and extract the URL part. Also checking == on the original string will fail because it will contain an url and therefore it wont match. and there is an extra } on that script.

use javascript function .substr(start,length) to work with partial strings, see example at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

beware that this compare will be case sensitive, so you might consider using .toUpperCase()

on match use .substr(start) without length to have the rest of the string containing URL

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var question=prompt("Type in a question");
    if (question.toUpperCase().substr(0,14)==("CAN YOU GO TO " /*a website*/ )){
        window.location.href = question.substr(14)/*the website that the person typed in after to*/;
    }
</script>
```